# My android project is "using an old version of the Android Gradle plug-in"

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting this error

```
Project is using an old version of the Android Gradle plug-in. The minimum supported version is 0.6.3.

Please update the version of the dependency 'com.android.tools.build:gradle' in your build.gradle files.
```

So i did research and realized I had to go to my project build.gradle file and change this part of my dependencies

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
}
```

but my build.gradle file doesnt have that. This is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'android'

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile project(':Desktop:Coding:SlidingMenu-master:library')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:

updated code

```
 apply plugin: 'android'

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.4'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile project(':Desktop:Coding:SlidingMenu-master:library')
}
}


 android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
 }
```

new error

```
 No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileTree) values:  [directory 'libs']
 Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)

<a href="error in file: C:\Users\cmtc\Documents\Android\StayHealthy\build.gradle at line: 10">Build file 'C:\Users\cmtc\Documents\Android\StayHealthy\build.gradle' line: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `buildscript { ... }` block containing the `dependencies { classpath ... }` block you showed above (and also a `repositories { ... }` block). Such a block must be available at least in the root project's build script, or `apply plugin: "android"` won't work.

Comment: How do I get those, this build.gradle file was generated. could you show an example?

Comment: See [Basic Project](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basic-Project) in the Gradle Android Plugin docs.

Comment: I updated my code and now have a whole new set of problems. Why isnt eclipse exporting the proper .gradle file?

Comment: I don't know. `compile` dependencies need to go into a `dependencies` block *outside* `buildscript`. Only `classpath` dependencies go *inside* `buildscript`.

Comment: If you had more than one modules in Eclipse there should be a build.gradle at the root of your project structure (next to a settings .gradle). The location was displayed in the export wizard. This is the build.gradle file that contains the line you need to update.

Comment: @Xavier Ducrohet WHere do i find the root of my project structure? there is no settings.gradle

Comment: @XavierDucrohet ahhhh, my problem was finding where the root is. THANK YOU

Comment: @XavierDucrohet new problem, it didnt import the project it imported the entire user directory...